# I try to update a variants parameter 'option1' via API - getting {"errors":{"variant":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Tags: php, curl, shopify, shopify-app

I try to update a variants `option1`. If you look at the code below: The function `getVariant` will return a json of this variant, so the basic call as well as the authentication to the API works. The function `updateVariant` however only returns: `{"errors":{"variant":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}`

Most google results suggest to solve this error I have to set the Content-Type, which I did. But it did not change anything. What do I miss here?

I try to reproduce the call in this api reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant#update-2019-07

```
$varianturl ="https://".$api_key.":".$password."@".$shop."/admin/api/2019-07/variants/15990192209979.json";

print_r(getVariant($varianturl));
print_r(updateVariant($varianturl));


function getVariant($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

}

function updateVariant($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $params = array(
    "id"=> 15990192209979,
    "option1"=> "Not Pink",
    "price"=> "99.00"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see you are using private app concept to fetch and update the data from Shopify .

Kindly replace your code by this code

```
    $varianturl ="https://".$api_key.":".$password."@".$shop."/admin/api/2019-07/variants/15990192209979.json"; //15990192209979 this is a variant id
    print_r(getVariant($varianturl));
    print_r(updateVariant($varianturl));die;


    function getVariant($url) {
        $headers = [];
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($api_key.":".$password)."";
        $headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token:'.$password;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
         list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $data, 2);
        return $message_body;

    }

    function updateVariant($url) {
        $params = [];
        $params['variant'] = array(
        "id"=> 15990192209979, //this is product id not variant id
        "option1"=> "Not Pink",
        "price"=> "99.00"
        );
        $headers = [];
        $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:');
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($api_key.":".$password)."";
        $headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token:'.$password;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//deepak
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ohShopify-php-api-client');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
          list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $data, 2);
        return $message_body;

    }
```

For more knowledge about private app work kindly go through this link

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/private-authentication#make-authenticated-requests?

Comment: The real solution is right here: `$params['variant'] = array( ` I needed to put the `id`, `option1` and `price` into `variant` first (my params structure was not right). So I will mark your answer as correct. Can I ask a few questions? You do the authentication in the URL and in the header ("Authorization: Basic "). Is there a reason for it? For me it works well if I just do it in the URL. But maybe there are circumstances where the authentication in the header is better?

Comment: As per the shopify guideline if you are try to call any api of shopify you just need to add header ("Authorization: Basic ")  this is important for security check 

When I tried to fetch information of variant from shopify without header , i am getting this error {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"} , So header is important to make connection with shopify

Comment: @ankitsingh..I've updated your answer to reflect the correct usage of variant API. You need to use variant id and not the product id. Check the url of the request, it points to variant id

Comment: @nbar .. regarding the variant array you are correct. For authentication, you can use either URL authentication or Header BASIC Auth. Both work technically the same.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot expect a GET data structure to just work as a PUT data structure. Instead, use the data from the GET to map to a PUT following the guidelines of a PUT on a variant, something the documentation clearly shows you. Simply saying option1 is equal to 'test' is never going to work, what is Shopify supposed to do with that? Be more specific. Provide an ID for example as a start.

Comment: I did test it with providing the ID too. I edited the code to add the ID to the params. However the results are the same. The rest I tried to copy from existing examples or direct from the API page, for example here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant#update-2019-07

Comment: Well it is no surprise your PUT fails. Your URL is incorrect for one thing. And then you might have to tackle the option changes from the product perspective too. You cannot change something on one specific variant that affects all of them. To do that, you would approach from the product itself, which in turn would apply that change to all variants.

Comment: URL should be correct. I updated the code to use the same url like here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant#update-2019-07 (the only difference is to call for a specific api version). I also updated the params to set the same 3 options like in the api reference. Yet I get the same error.

Comment: No, the URL is correct. The problem is in the `$params`. Your tip to look at the GET data structure more closely was helpful.